# It is possible to make a library that can be used in many languages?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c

It is possible to make a library that can be used in many languages?  Or at least a library that can be used in several languages.

If so, what documentation do you recommend me to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, by providing a C interface to it. Most if not all mayor languages provide the ability to bind to C functions.

Comment: @K-ballo this really deserves to be its own answer.

Comment: Yes, this is possible with C, .Net and Java libraries. If you can provide more detail on your requirements, we can provide more assistance. What platform/s do you want to run on, and with what languages?

Comment: What I want is to implement a standard for using it in as many languages as possible. I just want to know, for example how can I define classes, or the whole library to be used in several languages; for example create a library that I can use in .NET, Java AND C, the same implementation of the standard without having to modify the classes to work with all the platforms or right code for each platforms, What I want to avoid is to write the same library in all the languages I need the implementation.

Comment: Obviously, if you write it as classes, C won't like it, and if you write it as free functions, Java won't like it. You might be able to set up a scheme in which you compile a subset of Java to C (i.e. single class with no instance methods)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, by providing a C interface to it. Most if not all mayor languages provide the ability to bind to C functions.

Answer (score 3):

In .NET, any assembly you create can be used by any other .NET language.  So if you create a library in C#, you can make use of it in J#, C++.NET, VB.NET, etc.

Comment: So long as it is [CLS compliant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

The Java Virtual Machine(JVM) can [run many languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_JVM_languages) (not just Java).
Any library written in one of these languages can be called from another language on the list.

Answer (score 1):

[SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) can be used to automatically create many of the language wrappers everyone's talking about here. In many cases, the wrapper has two components: a C++ one that is rolled into your DLL, and one written in the language.

Answer (score 0):

A C library will be accessible from the most languages in the most environments.

However, you ask in your comment how to define classes for use in multiple languages. C has no classes. If you want an object-oriented API, you can:

- Define Java classes for use with languages running on the JVM.
- Define .NET classes for use with languages running on .NET.

One option, depending on what you're writing, may be to write a single implementation in C, then expose it via separate wrappers in C++, Java and .NET.

Comment: What do you mean by separate wrappers?

Comment: Let's say you want to provide a friendly API in many different languages -- and that some significant part of the library that can be written in C. You can create a single implementation of *part* of the library in C, then write one interface to it in Java, another in .NET, another in C++, another in Perl, etc. Your choice is not limited to either writing a single implementation or writing multiple disjoint implementations.

Answer (score 0):

A library can be created that can be used by more than one language.  One of the issues is the calling convention.

A **calling convention** defines how parameters are passed to a function as well as any setup required.  For example, one convention may specify that parameters are passed from right to left (the right most parameter first).  Some conventions say to pass values in the N registers; others demand that all parameters passed by address (pointer).

Some calling conventions may decrement a stack pointer, which is used by the function, for storing parameters.  Some may not even use a stack.

Yes, a library can be used by more than one language.  The trick is how to write code in a language to properly access functions in the library.